# MongoDB / C# - Project as a dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb

With this object:

```
class A
{
    string S;
    int V;
}
```

I am trying to do a projection like this (this won't compile)

```
Expression(_ => new KeyValuePair<string, int>() { _.S, _.V })
```

The goal being to get a Dictionary as an output.

Is there a way to do this?

I can do something like Include(_ => *.s).Include(* => *.V).Exclude(* => _._id) but, while I can cast that to a class, etc, I don't have a way to make this a dictionary; I can make it as a list, but I don't know how to assign S to key and V to value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to project as dictionary, could you do something like this?

```
var listA = await GetCollection().As<A>().ToListAsync();
var dictA = listA.ToDictionary(_=>_S, _=>_.V);
```

You can control the projection on the db side by including this in the query

```
.Project(Builders<Entity>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
```